# Matrix multiplication geometrical understanding

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, intuition

I was trying to understand Matrix Multiplication beyond just the algorithm I had to memorize in school. I came across this beautiful way to describe the dot product of two vectors as the area of a parallelogram like so.

[image]

This made vector multiplication very clear to me, is there a similar way to understand matrix multiplication in a geometric way? Especially for rectangular matrices which seem to crop up quite frequently.

Comment: You might find [the 3blue1brown video series on linear algebra](https://www.3blue1brown.com/essence-of-linear-algebra-page) to be helpful

Comment: In a nutshell: matrix multiplication corresponds to an application of successive linear transformations

Comment: You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24456/81360) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31725/81360) from this site to be helpful

Comment: Also, you might find [this perspective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3875249/81360) on the cross product interesting.